# How to write name with the letters in name?

Tags: tables

I got a question about how to write a name with the letters in  a name. I know how to use LaTeX but I couldnt find which code that I should use. You can see on the picture. [image: example]

If I make columns and write E&E.. then there is too much blank between letters.

Comment: Cell contents in different columns are separated by `&`, not each letter of   words.

Comment: you mean like EEE& &M& & & &M ?

Comment: Might be doable in verbatim, just use that env and type in exactly what is shown on the image.

Answer (score 8):

verbatim?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
  ____       _    __     __           ____   
 |  _"\  U  /"\  u\ \   /"/u  ___    |  _"\  
/| | | |  \/ _ \/  \ \ / //  |_"_|  /| | | | 
U| |_| |\ / ___ \  /\ V /_,-. | |   U| |_| |\
 |____/ u/_/   \_\U  \_/-(_/U/| |\u  |____/ u
  |||_    \\    >>  //   .-,_|___|_,-.|||_   
 (__)_)  (__)  (__)(__)   \_)-' '-(_/(__)_)  
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://www.figlet.org/

Comment: I used an online generator http://www.kammerl.de/ascii/AsciiSignature.php (random landing from google:-)

Answer (score 7):

Or use the typewriter font and `\` for fixed spaces:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\obeylines\parskip-4pt
\begin{document}
EEEE\ \\
M\ \ \ M\ \ RRR\ \ \   AAAA\ \\
H\ \ H
E\ \ \ \ \ MM\   MM\ \ R\ \ R\ \  A\ \ A\ \  H\ \ H 
EE\ \ \ \  M\ M\  M\ \ RRR\ \ \   AAAA\ \\
HHHH  
E\ \ \ \ \ M\ \ \ M\ \ R\ \ R\ \  A\ \ A\ \  H\ \ H 
EEEE\ \\
M\ \ \ M\ \ R\ \ R\ \  A\ \ A\ \  H\ \ H
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way of creating a background layer with the letters and then cutting out large letters from a solid overlay. This is, naturally, essentially overkill and it requires Ti*k*Z. But, heck, you have 2 sensible solutions already - or, at least, low-cost solutions - so it is time for something with more bells and whistles. They may serve no purpose and the output may look decidedly humdrum. But the important point is that *we know the bells and whistles are there hidden somewhere*.

[image: DONALD with don fading]

This uses a custom fading called `don` to create the cut out overlay and nested loops to create the background which shows through the `DONALD` shaped holes.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,fadings}
\newlength\myskip
\setlength\myskip{8.5pt}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=don]% manual 343
  \node [text=transparent!100, fill=transparent!0, draw=transparent!0, line width=5mm] {\fontfamily{ugq}\fontsize{45}{45}\bfseries\selectfont D\hskip\myskip O\hskip\myskip N\hskip\myskip\hskip2pt A\hskip\myskip L\hskip\myskip D};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    font=\ttfamily,
    node distance=0pt,
    inner sep=0pt,
  ]
  \foreach \k [remember=\k as \kold] in {1,...,7}
  {
    \foreach \i [count=\m, remember=\m as \mold] in {D,O,N,A,L,D}
    {
      \foreach \j [remember=\j as \jold (initially 0)] in {1,...,7}
      {
        \ifnum\jold=0
          \ifnum\m=1
            \ifnum\k=1
              \node (\k-\m-\j) {\i};
              \else \node [below=of \kold-1-1] (\k-\m-\j) {\i};
            \fi
            \else \node [right=of \k-\mold-7] (\k-\m-\j) {\i};
          \fi
          \else \node [right=of \k-\m-\jold] (\k-\m-\j) {\i};
        \fi
      }
    };
  };
  \path [scope fading=don, fading transform={shift=(current bounding box.center)}, fit fading=false, fill=white] (0,0);
  \node (back) [inner sep=0pt, fill=white, fit=(1-1-1) (7-6-7)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If we add

```
every node/.style={text=white, fill=black},
```

to the settings for the `tikzpicture` and change the last node to

```
  \node (back) [inner sep=0pt, top color=black, bottom color=black, middle color=white, fit=(1-1-1) (7-6-7)] {};
```

we can make it a bit more dramatic.

[image: more dramatic version]